# Adding a subtle animation when hiding elements and revealing them -CSS -JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm adding a hidden class and removing a hidden class when buttons are clicked in my project. Pretty straightforward. But instead of simply hiding the elements and showing them is there a way I can have them quickly rollout and rollup? I'm not a great front-end guy YET, Here is my Javascript:

## JS

```
$(document).on("click", _this.sel.close, function(event) {
  $(".update-billing").addClass("hidden");
  $(".billing-stats").removeClass("hidden");
  $(".current-cc").removeClass("hidden");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

What are some good resources for learning about animations?

Comment: You mean your jQuery. That's not Javascript. Anyways, what you're wanting is something accordion-like, which actually can be implemented statically these days. An example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/abergin/pen/ihlDf?editors=1100#0).

Comment: Isn't jQuery also JS? Also thanks for the help!

Comment: jQuery is a library built on javascript, but it's not javascript in that things like slideUp() or slideToggle() (custom extensions in jQuery) are not fundamental to javascript. To learn about jQuery effects, take a look at https://jqueryui.com/effect/  But another option to consider is CSS animations, like https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: As Snowmonkey, it's a javascript library, not native JS. I'm a stickler for this emphasis because I'm one of the many purists that thinks mapping `$` to `document.querySelectorAll` ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)) is a good substitute for the entire bloated library these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS solution**:

```js
$(document).on("click", 'span', function(event) {
  $(".slider").toggleClass("hidden");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.slider {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.hidden {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  Content
</div>
<span>Click me</span>
```

Downside: You have to work with fixed heights of the divs and might not be supported by every browser you need: [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition)

**JS Solution**:

```js
$(document).on("click", 'span', function(event) {
  $(".slider").slideToggle();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.slider {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  Content
</div>
<span>Click me</span>
```

*Reference*

[css transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

[.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: As a note on the fixed heights, if you animate on `max-height` and also animate top and bottom `padding`, you can trick the user's eye into animating it smoothly and avoid a fully-fixed height.